# concrete method in abstract class and default method in interface having the same name

Tags: java, java-8, interface, abstract-class, default-method

I have declared the default method and concrete method in the abstract class with the same name.

```
public class AbstractClassDefaultMethodTest   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoInterface testDefaultMethods=new TestDefaultMethods();
        testDefaultMethods.display();
    }
}
abstract class DemoClass{

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside display method of abstract class");
    }
}

interface DemoInterface{

    public default void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside display method of interface");
    }
}

class TestDefaultMethods extends DemoClass implements DemoInterface
{

}
```

Why the concrete method of abstract class is getting called? Why we are not getting the compile time error, as both the method names are same ?

Comment: Why do you expect a compiler error? The method in `DemoClass` simply *overrides* the method of the same name in `DemoInterface`. And you know how overridden methods work.

Comment: default methods have only been made possible since java 8. They had to be able to implement them, without breaking existing code, so that means adding a default method shouldn't be allowed to break code or change functionality.